# Setting selected item in F# ComboBox

Tags: winforms, combobox, f#

This is driving me nuts....

I'm trying to set the "selected" item of the `Windows.Forms.ComboBox`. I've tried everything but nothing has worked so far. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious...

Here's what I have (in F#):

```
type Foo = {
    id : int;
    name : string;
}

let foos = [// list of Foos ]

// This is what I want to comboBox to display by default
let defFoo = { id = 3; name = "defaultFoo"; } 


let cb = new ComboBox()
cb.DataSource <- foos |> List.toArray
cb.DisplayMember <- "name"
cb.ValueMember <- "id"

cb.SelectedValue <- defFoo.id
```

The last line doesn't work, as none of the other methods I tried. (I tried `SelectedItem`, `SelectedIndex`, etc.)

Comment: Did you add this ComboBox to your form?

Comment: @LarsTech Yes, sure. Otherwise how would I know that it doesn't display the item that I want it to? It always displays the first item in the `foos` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use f# much, but I think the form needs to exist before the data binding works, so try using the Load or Shown event:

```
yourForm.Load.Add(fun evArgs -> cb.SelectedValue <- defFoo.id)
```